# Is there any module which list all hyperlinks from content page

Tags: 7, nodes, navigation

Hi i want the list of all hyperlinks present in the page.
As i needed to change the path of the all pages to content/mypage/pagetitle.
In my case there are around 5o pages and having more than 100 hyperlinks in each page.
So i want to know any module in drupal which can list all hyperlinks pagewise.
please help if you know anything.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than doing this from within Drupal, have you considered using a tool such as Xenu Link Sleuth? http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html

Comment: i have the module link checker in drupal 7 which shows the broken links but i need to update all hyperlinks so i needed to know any module which updates all hyperlinks in the content.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Are you changing hyperlinks withing body text?  What is the form of the existing hyperlinks? Are the content/mypage/pagetitle links drupal path aliases for nodes?

Comment: I was about say use the link checker module, but I see you tried that. Might be time to look into apache mod_rewrite. This question could use some clarifying, I like rooby's questions.

Comment: Hey rooby, I have used book_copy module to create a new book from existing one.The newly created book has the new url aliases as content/mypage/pagetitle where for old book it was content/pagetitle. after successfully copying the book i found that the links which are in the content are showing the link to the old content. So i needed to update all links which are in the content.please let me know is there any module for that.